# Eclipse Formatter - Wrapped parenthesis each on new line

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I would like to be able to customize Eclipse's formatter so that (where necessary) blocks wrapped by parenthesis can be formatted such that both the opening and closing parenthesis are on their own lines. (Like Allman style but for parenthesis instead of braces)

```
@Annotation
(
  value1 = true,
  value2 = "this one is a string"
)
public void MyMethod
(
  int param1,
  String param2,
  double param3
)
{
  //do something
}
```

The best I've been able to get:

```
@Annotation(
  value1 = true,
  value2 = "this one is a string")
public void MyMethod(
  int param1,
  String param2,
  double param3)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: In eclipse go to `windows -> preferences` on the left side open `Java -> expend code style -> Formatter`

Go to New... add your own format. test with annotation in preview see if it match with the one you wanted.

Comment: I have already done that, as indicated by what I showed after "The best I've been able to get". I was hoping there would be some trick that I haven't found, but to be honest my hopes are not too high

Comment: I'm also looking for something similar to this. What I'm looking for would place the closing parentheses on the same line as the opening bracket if followed by a block and on its own line otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently tried the options again? I found these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse in probably 5 years, sorry!